How to call the same API when user clicks on Retry in Angular 11+?
Whenever an API takes more than 30 seconds to give response I want to stop the loader and simply show Retry button on page.
And when user clicks on that button I want to call same API.
This whole procedure I want to implement in my whole project so I want this to be in common function and UI.
Can anyone help me to achieve this globally? As I doesn't want to write the same logic in each and every page.
If possible I want to edit my interceptor such that if API doesn't responds in 30 sec then it shows the Retry button in component/page. Now when from the component Retry button is pressed the same API gets called again.
Note: API should be called again only on the press of button and hence we can't use the retry method of rxjs.
Let me know if any other rxjs elements can help to achieve this.

I tried to achieve what you want via a service and an interceptor.
The main idea is to have your root app component watch the err variable on the service that throws a timeout. I am using an html dialog so that the error is rendered above other components.
Full Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c12rhx?file=src%2Fmain.ts
main.ts/app.component:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { DelayedService } from './delayed.service';
import {
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  provideHttpClient,
  withInterceptorsFromDi,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { GlobalHttpInterceptorService } from './global-http.interceptor';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DialogModule } from './dialog.module';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, DialogModule],

  template: `
    <h1>value: {{ res }}</h1>
    <app-dialog/>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(public delayedService: DelayedService) {}
  res: any;

  makeRequest() {
    this.delayedService
      .makeRequest('get', 'https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000', {
        responseType: 'text',
      })
      .subscribe((res) => (this.res = res));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeRequest();
  }

  retry() {
    this.delayedService.retryLastRequest().subscribe();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: GlobalHttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
});


dialog.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DelayedService } from './delayed.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  template: ` 
  <dialog *ngIf="!!(err$ | async)" open>
    <p>Conntection timed out</p>
    <form method="dialog">
      <button (click)="retry()">Retry</button>
    </form>
  </dialog>
`,
})
export class DialogComponent {
  constructor(public delayedService: DelayedService) {}
  err$ = this.delayedService.err;
  retry() {
    this.delayedService.retryLastRequest().subscribe();
  }
}


dialog.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DialogComponent],
  exports: [DialogComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class DialogModule {}


The global-http.interceptor.ts file intercepts and implements the desired timeout.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class GlobalHttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(timeout(3000));
  }
}


The service that makes the http calls makes sure to set the err variable on the service. It can be injected and called in any child component while still reporting the error centrally in app.component.ts.
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, catchError, map, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DelayedService {
  err = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  lastRequestMethod: 'get' | 'post' = 'get';
  lastRequestUrl: string = '';
  lastRequestOptions: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  makeRequest(method: 'get' | 'post', url: string, options: any = {}) {
    this.err.next(null);
    this.lastRequestUrl = url;
    this.lastRequestOptions = options;
    return this.http[method](url, options).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        this.err.next(err);
        return throwError(() => err);
      })
    );
  }

  retryLastRequest() {
    this.err.next(null);
    const url = this.lastRequestUrl;
    const options = this.lastRequestOptions;
    return this.http[this.lastRequestMethod](url, options).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        this.err.next(err);
        return throwError(() => err);
      })
    );
  }
}


Hope this helps, let me know if anything is unclear or wrong.
You might wanna cache the last request and write a more central retry method. If you need help with that just let me know in the comments.

You could create an interceptor that uses timeout and catchError.
Assuming you have some Modal Service that will display the modal and return a Observable<boolean> indicating if the user chose to retry or not, you can do something like this:
export const timeoutInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const modal = inject(ModalService);

  return next(req).pipe(
    timeout(30_000),
    catchError(() => modal.confirm('Request Failed! Retry?').pipe(
      switchMap(retry => retry ? next(req) : EMPTY)
    ))
  );

The above code uses timeout to throw an error if an emission doesn't occur before the specified duration. Then inside of catchError we return an observable that emits a boolean indicating whether or not to retry.  Finally we use switchMap to return the final observable based on the boolean, emitting next(req) on true and EMPTY on false.

If you want the timeout / retry logic to apply to requests launched after clicking "retry", you can pull the logic into a recursive function like this:
export const timeoutInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const modal = inject(ModalService);

  const handleRequest: HttpHandlerFn = req => {
    return next(req).pipe(
      timeout(30_000),
      catchError(() => modal.confirm('Request Failed! Retry?').pipe(
        switchMap(retry => retry ? handleRequest(req) : EMPTY)
      ))
    );
  };

  return handleRequest(req);
};

Here is a StackBlitz example.
